# Hide/Show route layer in Leaflet when click on button (Easy Button plugin)

Tags: jquery, button, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map with button (Easy Button plugin https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton). When click on button on map added route layer (plugin https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine). Please, help me add event for button to show/hide layer when I click on button.
Map example:

Code example:http://spatialhast.github.io/leaflet.routing.html

```
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [50.0669, 35.1638],
        zoom: 15
    });

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy; Map Data <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);


    L.easyButton('fa-level-up',
        function() {

            var routing = L.Routing.control({
                plan: L.Routing.plan([
                    L.latLng(50.07132, 35.14103),
                    L.latLng(50.05459, 35.18239)
                ], {
                    waypointIcon: function(i) {
                        return new L.Icon.Label.Default({
                            labelText: String.fromCharCode(65 + i)
                        });
                    },
                    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
                }),
                routeWhileDragging: true,
                routeDragTimeout: 250
            });

    var rlayer = L.layerGroup([routing]);
    map.hasLayer(rlayer) ? map.removeLayer(rlayer) : map.addLayer(rlayer);      

    },
        'Display Route'
    ).addTo(map);
```

I use `map.hasLayer(rlayer) ? map.removeLayer(rlayer) : map.addLayer(rlayer);` but route layer after second click don't hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the variable rlayer outside of the easybutton function. Try that:

```
var rlayer = null;
L.easyButton('fa-level-up',
function() {
if(rlayer) {
  map.removeLayer(rlayer);
  rlayer = null;
} else {
  var routing = L.Routing.control(...);
  rlayer = L.layerGroup([routing]);
  map.addLayer(rlayer);      
}
}, 'Display Route' ).addTo(map);
```

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130948/hide-show-route-layer-in-leaflet-when-click-on-button-easy-button-plugin

Answer (score 0):

use L.control.layers (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-l.control) 
for your route layer. It will add a button on your map. You can switch the layer by using that button.

Comment: Thanks! But I want show/hide route layer using Easy Button, not Layer control.

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
 var rlayer = L.layerGroup([routing]);
    map.hasLayer(rlayer) ? map.removeLayer(rlayer) : map.addLayer(rlayer);      

    },
        'Display Route'
    ).addTo(map);
```

Just .addTo(map); and then you can use :

routing.hide();

that will do the trick and show to show it again!